# WPF show small number beside all Controls

Tags: wpf, templates, text, markup-extensions

I have many FrameworkElements (TextBlock, CheckBox, ListBox..) and I would like to make something allowing me to show a small number besides every one control.

**Some text ³**

I came with the idea to write a MarkupExtension, where I could write that number like this:

```
..
<TextBlock Text="Some Text" SomeExtension="3" />
..
```

and then to add it somehow to the template of the Control.

But I'm sure, you guys have better solution for this problem ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go with it would be create a `Attached Property`. Upon setting it on a control, a custom `Adorner` would be added for that control showing specified number.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tag property to provide the number you want and inside the custom template databind to the property

```
<TextBlock Text="Some Text" Tag="3" />
```

and inside the controltemplate

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag}"/>
```